# I'm not earning reputation on an answer to a community-wiki question

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

I want to know why I am not getting any reputation points on a **Community-Wiki** question (which appears to also be *protected*) that I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286846/describe-the-architecture-you-use-for-java-web-applications/32822065#32822065). I got 2 upvotes but it is not reflecting in my reputation.

Why is it so? Can anyone tell me the exact reason of it?

Comment: That looks like a question that should have been closed. It's one of the classic GTKY questions of yore.

Comment: I didn't understood what you mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The entire question is [*Community Wiki*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/258928). Therefore, your answer has been automatically converted to a CW answer.

As such, you can't get any reputation from it.

> - Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation.

Comment: Thanks for your cool answer I will take care of it :)

Comment: Raj didn't make his answer Community Wiki, the entire question itself is CW, so that ***all answers*** must also be CW. CC @Raj.

Comment: @Cupcake: Thanks for the clarification. I had a doubt on that (edited accordingly).

Comment: Ohk thats great of you @cupcake Thanks for clarifying it :)

Comment: I can't understood why someone here is saying that this question should have to be closed  @Cupcake

Comment: @Raj: My first shot here would be voting to close it as *primarily opinion-based* or *too broad*.

Comment: @Raj "GTKY" means "Getting to Know You". The question isn't really a programming problem, it's more of an invitation to people to talk about how they've built their Java applications. While it may make for an interesting *discussion*, it's not really suited to the strict Question & Answers format of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do I need to close this question ?? @Cupcake

Comment: @Raj which question are you referring to, the one on Stack Overflow main, or this one here on Meta?

Comment: @Cupcake this one...

Comment: @Raj I don't see any reason to close it...maybe someone else will find it helpful in the future.

Comment: @Cupcake: Maybe the title should be rephrased to "*I'm not earning reputation on an answer to a **community-wiki** question*" as the question being protected is irrelevant here.

Comment: @D4V1D you're welcome to change it, though I wouldn't touch it until after it's closed, as it has close votes on it, and editing it will kick it out of the close review queue.

Comment: @Cupcake: Done :)